# VBScript file starts wscript.exe but doesn't execute code

Tags: vbscript, wsh

When I double-click my `.vbs` file in Windows, it will start the `wscript.exe` process, but doesn't appear to execute anything. Even a simple "Hello World" script doesn't do anything—not even an error message from an invalid command. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Check your Windows event logs to see if a Software Restriction Policy or anti-virus access protection policy may be preventing scripts from executing.  If security auditing of process terminations is enabled, then you can review the exit code of the wscript.exe process for more details in the Security event log.  Process Monitor may be able to provide more details, assuming you're an administrator on the PC.

Comment: Can you share your code?